# Actulización de sitemap con curl

Tags: curl, sitemap

Buenas tardes necesito de su apoyo estoy tratando de ahacer un bas script para avisar a google que mi sitemap tiene una actualización [link de ejemplo que da google](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v1/sitemaps/submit?hl=es-419&apix_params=%7B%22siteUrl%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Ftest.com%22%2C%22feedpath%22%3A%22sitemaps%2Fsitemap.xml%22%7D#try-it)

este es el script que estoy intentando usar:

```
#!/bin/bash

API_KEY='apikey'  
SITE_URL="https://test.com"
SITEMAPS=('google_news' 'sitemap')
API_URL="https://searchconsole.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites"
echo "=== PING Sitemaps ==="

DESKTOP=""

for i in "${SITEMAPS[@]}"
do
  echo "*** GOOGLE APIS ($i) ***"
  URL="https://searchconsole.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/https://test.com/sitemaps/https://test.com/sitemaps/$i.xml?key=$API_KEY"
  echo "URL:$URL"

  curl --request PUT \
      'https://searchconsole.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/https%3A%2F%2Ftest.com/sitemaps/https%3A%2F%2Ftest.com%2Fsitemap.xml?key=$API_KEY' \
      --header 'Authorization: Bearer $API_KEY' \
      --header 'Accept: application/json' \
      --compressed

  echo "*** BING PING ($i) ***"
  URL="https://www.bing.com/ping?sitemap=$SITE_URL/sitemaps/$i.xml"
  echo " URL: $i.xml"
  curl -s -I -A "$DESKTOP" $URL && echo " - Exitoso" || echo " - Error -"
done
```

pero me saca este error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid Credentials",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "authError",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

alguien me orienta como solucionarlo, gracias de antemano